# AngularJS grunt task - npm install error related to npm package-karma-phantomjs-launcher

Tags: angularjs, npm, gruntjs, phantomjs

I have dug a lot to fix this issue in my current angularjs project, the same issue came in my previous project and at that time I skipped the issue using --force. But this time I can't proceed with --force. I am attaching the error log and package.json here. Please go through it and suggest me a solution.

What I have tried is uninstall/reinstall node.js, *npm cache clean*, run commands as Administrator etc. The issue comes when I try to install the node packages using *npm install* command.

Edit : After I install phantomjs globally the error changed, updated the screenshot below.

**Error**
[image]

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "yourprojectname",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "CMF",
  "homepage": "http://recomm.com/",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "~0.5",
    "grunt-browser-output": "0.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.6",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.7",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.9",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.8",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6",
    "grunt-dom-munger": "~3.4",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.8.3",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-replace": "^1.0.1",
    "karma": "~0.12.6",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "~0.2.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2"
  }
}
```

**Versions I have**

```
grunt - v0.4.5
grunt-cli - v1.2.0
node - v6.11.0
npm - 3.10.11
```

Comment: Try executng `npm set strict-ssl false` and `npm install` afterwards.

Comment: Tried but no use. Question updated, please check.

Comment: did you try it in administrator mode?

Comment: Yes. The issue is associated with package- karma-phantomjs-launcher

Comment: For a temporary fix again !! I have installed karma-phantomjs-launcher prior to run npm install . That works !!